# htmlentities works on browser only when called twice

Tags: php, database, html-entities

Now here's a totally weird behaviour I'm experiencing with PHP: `htmlentities` doesn't seem to work when called; Thus, when I do:

```
echo htmlentities("&lt;iframe&gt;");
```

the browser outputs the string argument unescaped, i.e. `&lt;iframe&gt;`.

However, when I call the function twice, it works:

```
echo htmlentities(htmlentities("&lt;iframe&gt;"));
```

giving me: `&amp;lt;iframe&amp;gt;`

I noticed the weird behaviour [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16908148/2334352) where the user expressed the same confusion.

Now I have two issues with using this "answer which works": firstly, I know this is a strange behaviour, and there's no guarantee that this strangeness will be replicated (I hope it isn't!) when my code is exported to another server. Secondly, why this behaviour in the first place?

So my issue: I would love to know the origin of this behaviour and what to do about it.

It's a shame a lot of you won't be able to verify my problem, given I'm working on my localhost and `htmlentities` works fine on other servers.

Comment: This isn't just for PHP 7, I'm getting the same results as you on 5.6.23 so this must go further back.

Comment: View Source and you'll see you are getting the correct results.

Comment: "the browser outputs the string argument unescaped, i.e. <iframe>." As in you see `<iframe>` in the view-source mode? Or you see `<iframe>` output on the screen?

Comment: @PHPglue *arg!!!* of course. You hit the nail right on the head. I should have looked at source.

Comment: @PHPglue I never said it was a problem ;-) it just explains what the op probably didn't do. Edit: you deleted your comment.

Comment: You should remove that comment, because it confuses OP, but you're funny.

Comment: Therefore, it's the browser tricking you. I don't think this is necessarily a bug, more of a misinterpretation; a "switcheroo" if I could say.

Comment: @PHPglue I'm not following; you want me to remove my comment on the basis of what the OP thinks is a bug, when in fact it's the web browser rearranging it back to a readable format. I don't get that.

Comment: @PHPglue, Let's forget the browser, I'm using a database and it saves raw HTML, no encoding

Comment: *"Let's forget the browser, I'm using a database and it saves raw HTML, no encoding"* - Then you're not showing us the whole picture here and how you're inserting that and which functions/API used etc. That "database" comment now, is a whole new ballgame; you threw us all a curve ball if I could say. So now, the plot thickens, as it were.

Comment: I agree with @Fred-ii- How are you rendering what's in your DB? CLI? Workbench? PHPMyAdmin? If it's that last one, you're still viewing the DB output through your browser

Comment: Why would one ever save raw HTML to a database? You should encode it first, so you don't have string issues, at least.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I was outputting database values on the browser, so Yes, browser was still tricking me. Thanks guys!

Comment: [*Yeah, I said that "tricking you" bit earlier, didn't I?...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008270/why-would-htmlentities-sometimes-work-only-when-called-twice#comment65368451_39008270)

Comment: You should have posted the real code you were using in regards to the database (what you were doing at the time of output) and would avoided all these comments and confusion. Only then, would you have gotten a straight answer from a straight question and I for one, would have told you that. The mystery has been solved in comments, far as I'm concerned ;-)

Comment: @PHPglue The recommended standard is store raw, output escaped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253532/html-xss-escape-on-input-vs-output http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/ http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9415/filter-user-input-before-the-database-or-upon-display

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by the browser interpreting the results

```
echo htmlentities(htmlentities("<iframe>"));
```

Produces (raw output)

```
&amp;lt;iframe&amp;gt;
```

Pass one converts the `<>` into `&lt;iframe&gt;`
Pass two is converting the `&` into `&amp;`

When your browser renders it, the `&amp;` is then rendered as `&`, producing the output in your question. if you view the source you'll see what I posted above.

So it's working as intended. [See a demo](https://3v4l.org/7kLmX)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Machavity, but you missed my point. When called twice, the browser outputs the results as though it were called once. See my example on the output when called twice, it's different from the output you've given.

Comment: @che-azeh I think you missed what I was saying. I've tried to clarify this some more, but you're being confused by the browser rendering `&amp;` as `&`

Comment: Oh, I get it :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because when you encode the string `<iframe>` the output is sent to the browser as `&lt;iframe&gt;`.

Now if you were to look at the *source* of the response you'd see `&lt;iframe&gt;` as expected, but if you're looking at the *rendered page* your browser will show the decoded string `<iframe>`.

The reason why "it works" when you double-encode it is because your browser strips off only one layer of encoding for display. So the raw source sent to the browser is `&amp;lt;iframe&amp;gt;`, but the displayed text is `&lt;iframe&gt;`.

Answer (score 1):

`htmlentities("<iframe>");` creates `&lt;iframe&gt;` which will output to the Client just as you put it in the quotes, since the Browser interprets `&lt;` as `<` and `&gt;` as `>` . Once, you run it again on top of that, you are really doing this `htmlentities('&lt;iframe&gt;')`, which evaluates to `&amp;lt;iframe&amp;gt;` which displays in a Browser as `&lt;iframe&gt;`. Hopefully this is just easier to understand for you than `@Machavity`'s answer.